# GWT StackLayoutPanel with multiple stacks visible at the same time

Tags: java, gwt

I have a StackLayoutPanel, with multiple stacks. I now need to change it so that multiple stacks can be shown at the same time.

Does anyone know a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you'd like to change your StackLayoutPanel into a series of [DisclosurePanels](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DisclosurePanel.html) (e.g. contained in a FlowPanel). So you could expand each of them individually. With a little bit of styling, this might end up looking similar to a StackLayoutPanel.

Comment: I tried this, worked out great. I managed to keep the same layout with just a few lines of modified css. The animation effect of DisclosurePanel gives a similar feeling when using the stacked DisclosurePanels. Thanks!

Comment: The only trouble would be getting a constant height for the whole stack and losing the `ProvidesResize`, but if you don't need that I think this is an elegant solution.